# CUDA 5.0's command line profiler?

Tags: cuda, opencl, profiler

Has anyone tried new CUDA 5.0's command line profiler? In earlier version it worked well for both CUDA and OpenCL. But in 5.0, when tested with GTX680, I can only produce the output file (cuda_profile_0.log) for cuda programs. For OpenCL programs, no profile output is produced. Am I missing any configuration or something like that? Or is that just there is no support for OpenCL profiling in CUDA 5.0?

Comment: Did you ever found a work around ?

Comment: So far not yet. But I think it is just the problem of Cuda 5.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OpenCL is not supported by nvprof. Please note that nvprof is a new tool in CUDA Toolkit 5.0 so it never supported OpenCL.

Comment: I wasn't really talking about nvprof. In previous version, what I had to do is just setting the environment variable COMPUTE_PROFILE=1 and the command line profiler will automatic produce profiling results whenever I run a CUDA or OpenCL program. Did you mean that in CUDA 5.0, this has completely changed?

Comment: @thanhtuan basically, it was rewritten from scratch.

Comment: Basically it looks, like Nvidia is closing the case on OpenCL pushing CUDA more and more. And not caring for developers anymore...